# My PC does not boot initially, but does on restart

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Recently I updated Ubuntu to the latest version. Now I have a problem when I boot or start Ubuntu. My PC has Windows alongside Ubuntu 18.04. When I select Ubuntu to start, it shows the error message

> error  symbol grub-file-read- not found

and it hangs until I power off. When I restart Ubuntu, it boots successfully and works well. And then when I start my PC again a day later, the same problem exists while booting and I need to restart it again and then it starts booting. I get irritated when it takes multiple times to restart to successfully boot.

What can cause this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: your CapsLock Key seems to be stuck, maybe you can repair this?

Answer (score 4):

Your **GRUB boot configuration file** might have some issues .

1. Boot in **Ubuntu 18.04** & Login
2. Open **Terminal** or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Type this command & hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot to Ubuntu
5. *Post any errors you encountered (Hopefully None)*